# Firebase broken on M1 Mac

Tags: firebase, npm, apple-m1

I have a new MacBook Air M1. Firebase had been working up until I did an upgrade of firebase-tools from 9.7.0 to 9.8.0 last week. After the upgrade, I get this error every time I try to run any "firebase " statement.

There is no source code directly involved in this question, for the person who closed the original question. To replicate this issue you'd have to have an M1 mac and be using firebase.

How can I fix this problem?

(Note for others who have this problem, the answer was provided in comments by @RandomDude below: just downgrade firebase-tools to 9.7.0)

```
steve@steves-air functions % firebase
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __Z18sse42_is_availablev
  Referenced from: /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/sse4_crc32/build/Release/crc32c.node
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: __Z18sse42_is_availablev
  Referenced from: /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/sse4_crc32/build/Release/crc32c.node
  Expected in: flat namespace

zsh: abort      firebase
```

Comment: Is there a coding question here? Do you have some code that you're having difficulty with? If so, please include it and show us what is causing that error. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You may also want to include your XCode version as well as your firebase version, cocoapods version (CocoaPods 1.10.0 is required) and what firebase product you're using as there are many.

Comment: which `firebase-tools` do you have? had the same issue with `9.8.0` - downgrading to `9.7.0` made it work

Comment: @RandomDude that fixed it for me too. Thanks!

Comment: It's been raised as an issue on the github repo for firebase-tools.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3239

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Update on April 7, 2021

Updating to `firebase-tools@9.9.0` fixed the issue.

```
$ npm install -g firebase-tools
$ firebase --version
9.9.0
```

---

### Temporal Solution

As it mentioned in the above comment by [RandomDude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4856636/randomdude), downgrading to `9.7.0` made it work for me.

```
$ firebase --version

# This will give you the same error.
# So, look at the directory where firebase-tools are installed.

$ cat /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/package.json
{
  "name": "firebase-tools",
  "version": "9.8.0",
--- snip ---
```

Reinstall firebase-tools

```
$ npm uninstall -g firebase-tools
$ npm install -g firebase-tools@9.7.0
$ firebase --version
9.7.0
```

This is a temporal solution for me. Thanks to [RandomDude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4856636/randomdude).